# Python pandas an efficient way to see which column contains a value and use its coordinates as an offset

Tags: python, pandas

As part of trying to learn pandas I'm trying to reshape a spreadsheet. After removing non zero values I need to get some data from a single column.

For the sample columns below, I want to find the most effective way of finding the row and column index of the `cell` that contains the value `date` and get the value next to it. (e.g. here it would be `38477`.

In practice this would be a much bigger DataFrame and the `date` row could change and it may not always be in the first column.

What is the best way to find out where `date` is in the array and return the value in the adjacent cell?

Thanks

```
<bound method DataFrame.head of             0         1         2         4         5         7         8         10  \
1   some title                                                                         
2         date     38477                                                               
5                   cat1                cat2                cat3                cat4   
6                      a         b         c         d         e         f         g   
8            Z  167.9404  151.1389   346.197  434.3589  336.7873  80.52901  269.1486   
9            X   220.683   56.0029  73.73679  428.8939  483.7445  251.1877  243.7918   
10           C  433.0189  390.1931  251.6636  418.6703  12.21859   113.093    136.28   
12           V  226.0135  418.1141  310.2038  153.9018  425.7491  73.08073  277.5065   
13           W   295.146  173.2747  2.187459  401.6453  51.47293   175.387  397.2021   
14           S  306.9325  157.2772  464.1394   216.248  478.3903   173.948  328.9304   
15           A  19.86611  73.11554   320.078  199.7598  467.8272  234.0331  141.5544
```

Comment: can you give some more context?  Why would you load this into a dataframe first, instead of parsing it as text, etc?

Comment: Hi @JeffTratner thanks for the response. I'm a complete n00b at python so I don't know why I would except that its what I would do in `R`. Would be pleased to hear that there is a better way. I use something like `[i for i in p if any(j == 'date' for j in p[i])]` and `[i for i in p.index if any(j == 'date' for j in p.ix(i)]` at the moment but it feels unwieldy. This is actually a series of daily update spreadsheets that come in from various sources that  The `date` and `sometitle` information need to be converted to additional fields in that database.

Comment: For example, do you need the rest of the spreadsheet, or are you just looking to pull out the date from this?

Comment: hi @JeffTratner, yes I do need the rest of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really just reformats a lot of the iteration you are doing to make it clearer and take advantage of pandas ability to easily select, etc.

First, we need a dummy dataframe (with date in the last row and explicitly ordered the way you have in your setup)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4,np.NaN], 
                   "B":[5, 3, np.NaN, 3, "date"],
                   "C":[np.NaN,2, 1,3, 634]})[["A","B","C"]]
```

A clear way to do it is to find the row and then enumerate over the row to find `date`:

```
row = df[df.apply(lambda x: (x == "date").any(), axis=1)].values[0] # will be an array
for i, val in enumerate(row):
    if val == "date":
        print row[i + 1]
        break
```

If your spreadsheet only has a few non-numeric columns, you could go by column, check for date and get a row and column index (this may be faster because it searches by column rather than by row, though I'm not sure)

```
# gives you column labels, which are `True` if at least one entry has `date` in it
# have to check `kind` otherwise you get an error.
col_result = df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype.kind == "O" and (x == "date").any())

# select only columns where True (this should be one entry) and get their index (for the label)
column = col_result[col_result].index[0]
col_index = df.columns.get_loc(column)

# will be True if it contains date
row_selector = df.icol(col_index) == "date"

print df[row_selector].icol(col_index + 1).values
```

Comment: thanks @JeffTratner. I'll give this one a go.. although it sounds like your applymap solution could work too.